# C - valgrind : uninitialised values with printf

Tags: c, printf, valgrind

I've got a problem with valgrind in the following code :

```c
48:    int X = 0, Y = 0;
49:    taille(n2, &X, &Y);
50:    printf("Taille du labyrinthe : X = %d ; Y = %d\n", X, Y);
```

It prints what I want to print but valgrind says :

```
==31566== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==31566==    at 0x48DFAD8: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==31566==    by 0x48C9EBE: printf (printf.c:33)
==31566==    by 0x1098AA: main (main.c:50)
==31566== 
==31566== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==31566==    at 0x48C381B: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==31566==    by 0x48DF6F4: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==31566==    by 0x48C9EBE: printf (printf.c:33)
==31566==    by 0x1098AA: main (main.c:50)
```

I think it's because I change the value of X and Y with taille() before I print it but I can't see what is the problem exactly. I already tried to declare pointers instead of integers or to declare pointers which point on X and Y and then pass them as arguments in taille() but it didn't change anything.

Here is the code of my function taille() just in case   *(parcours() returns an integer)* :

```
void taille(noeud n, int *X, int *Y)
{
    *X += parcours(n, EST, n);
    *X += parcours(n, OUEST, n);
    *Y += parcours(n, NORD, n);
    *Y += parcours(n, SUD, n);
}
```

Comment: Maybe `parcours` returns the value from an uninitialized variable?

Comment: Valgrind has an option `--track-origins=yes` that tells you where the uninitialized value comes from. That may give you more infomation.

Comment: Is `n2` initialized?

Comment: Please prepare a [mre], i.e. an **entire compilable program with `main` that produces the problem. While doing that you'll figure out yourself what the problem is.

Comment: @MOehm thank you for the option, I tried it and it seems to come from the initialisation of my node `n2`

Answer (score 2):

Ok sorry, I tried valgrind with `--track-origins=yes` and it comes from my node struct, I didn't initialise it correctly so now it works.